# I need to do a React.js app that logs in into an API to get the session key from the current session using Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I apologize if it doesnt make much sense, I am new to stackoverflow and React

I already made the React app, my problem is that I dont understand how to login into an API and making a GET request to get the current session key.

I have tried following axios docs  and fetch but the only thing I get is or Network error or a CORS error.

this is with axios

```
// class LoginForm extends React.Component {
//      state = {
//      users: []
//   }
//   componentDidMount() {
//     const url = API_URL;
//     axios.get(url)
//     .then(res=> {
//         const users = res.data;
//         this.setState({users});
//     })

//     }
//     render() {
//         return (
//          <div>{Object.keys(this.state.users).map(user => <h3>{user.skey}</h3> )}</div>
//         )
//     };
// }
```

this is with fetch

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API_URL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.items
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
```

this is the JSON from the API (I had altered content for security)

```
{
    "skey": "lep8k7jcbtba2Hwlcf4ZGVtgbmwo8s56721",
    "authenticated": false,
    "silo": "demo",
    "user": {
        "uuid": "f205daa8-b838-41c7-984be",
        "username": "guest",
        "full_name": "Guest",
        "email": "guest",
        "groups": [
            {
                "uuid": "27e2e4f9-ebee-4ecca10151",
                "name": "guest_user"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "c354f1b5-ca702fe3",
                "name": "public"
            }
        ],
        "roles": [
            {
                "uuid": "027a210b657f52b10dd4",
                "name": "limited"
            }
        ],
        "permits": [
            {
                "uuid": "e1e896-c5bd-35494211374e",
                "name": "collection.create.ccpUser"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "0e4a0a9c-8cca9-4803da46d23d",
                "name": "contribution.create.ccpArticle"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "83f93b4dab-116dd29b19e3",
                "name": "contribution.view.ccpComment"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "b7401658-4509-98e28868748b",
                "name": "view_pub_public"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "0016447d-af2b-3c4dd0bcf55d",
                "name": "ws.config.list"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "0c776bcb-7656-6e15-9ecb2389ea6f",
                "name": "ws.pubs"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "4839a09b-5be-b119-3ee8281780e3",
                "name": "ws.user.login"
            }
        ]
    },
    "httpSession": "devtvowc4gmo8s5672",
    "cmsVersion": "6.3p"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `res` around parenthesis. Try this:

```
axios.get(url)
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```